# Unable to run cucumber script in JUnit Test in Mac machine

Tags: eclipse, macos-big-sur, cucumber-junit

Following error is showing on running the code in the Mac machine with JDK 1.8 and eclispe.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because "com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.createBindings(ScriptBindings.java:160)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<init>(Tags.java:158)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<clinit>(Tags.java:48)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: That message looks like the improved null pointer exception message introduced in Java 14 - so you are not using Java 8. "Nashorn" is not in Java 15 or later.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have the correct version of Java

```
java -version
```

Will show you the version. You might be having multiple versions.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Will list all the versions available if you have multiple.

Then you can set the JAVA version manually before running any test. Something like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` && your_command
```